# free windows logs forwarding

Tags: windows, logging, syslog

I have the following problem.
I have some log files (In **Windows**) and i want to forward them via syslog to a centralised log server (Linux).

how could i do it ?

I used snare , syslogagent , kiwi but no one worked for my case.

Thanks

Comment: What didn't snare do that you needed it to?

Comment: snare worked very well for us as well

Comment: I deployed snare at last. For some reason it didn't work in the first place. Anyway. thanks everyone :>

Comment: please consider adding an answer saying that you decided to retry snare and that it worked.  Then accept that answer.

Answer (score 4):

[nxlog](http://nxlog.org) is open-source and can pull files and EventLog on windows. It can forward over UDP, TCP or SSL and it even supports the newer IETF syslog standard.

Answer (score 1):

We use Solarwinds Log Forwarder in our environment.

Comment: Thanks. I 'll have a look at it. Is it free ?

Answer (score 0):

Snare is a good one to use. You can also use the Lasso Client from Loglogic. Search for Lasso at http://loglogic.com.

No longer valid domain